Convert uppercase to title case
Following is my rust function to convert uppercase to titlecase (without removing the underscore). although I am able to achieve my goal but I don't think this is a good solution. Ignoring the nested loop, what am I doing wrong here. What's the correct way of thinking in rust for this problem.
fn convert_to_title_case(columns: &str) -> String {
    let split_columns = columns.split("\r\n");
    let mut converted_columns = String::new();


    for line in split_columns {
        
        let split_line = line.split("_");
        let mut converted_line = Vec::new();

        
        for word in split_line {
            let mut converted_word = String::new();
            match word.chars().nth(0) {
                Some(chr) => converted_word.push(chr),
                None => (),
            }
            converted_word.push_str(&word[1..word.len()].to_lowercase());
            converted_line.push(converted_word);
        }

        converted_columns.push_str(&converted_line.join("_"));
        converted_columns.push_str("\r\n");
    }

    converted_columns
}



able to achieve my goal but I don't think this is a good solution.

Right, it is a little long.
The OP code is easy to follow: we split on line terminators and then
on _ underscore. But we don't have to do either.
Also, if you're keen on splitting it could have been a single split on "\r\n_"
We accept N chars and emit N chars, some of them having a bit flipped.
It would be enough to do that with a single loop plus a state variable.
A boolean is_first shall be set True initially and when we encounter a word boundary.
For each char

copy it, downcasing unless is_first
assign is_first, so it is True exactly when current char is in "\r\n_"

Alternatively you could use a
regex
iterator to accomplish the same thing.
A more intuitive approach would be to downcase everything,
then come back to upcase immediately after each word boundary.

Remember that Rust strings are not arrays of char!

The problem with your code is that you are trying to convert the first letter of each word to uppercase, but in reality you are just copying the first letter without changing its case. Here is how you should fix your code:
fn convert_to_title_case(columns: &str) -> String {
    let split_columns = columns.split("\r\n");
    let mut converted_columns = String::new();

    for line in split_columns {
        let split_line = line.split("_");
        let mut converted_line = Vec::new();

        for word in split_line {
            let mut converted_word = String::new();
            match word.chars().nth(0) {
                Some(chr) => converted_word.push(chr.to_uppercase().collect::<String>().chars().nth(0).unwrap()),
                None => (),
            }
            converted_word.push_str(&word[1..word.len()].to_lowercase());
            converted_line.push(converted_word);
        }

        converted_columns.push_str(&converted_line.join("_"));
        converted_columns.push_str("\r\n");
    }

    converted_columns
}


I actually want to convert all chars except the first one to lower case.
